Write pure CSR components on Deno+Fresh
Sry that I'm new to front-end development.
I have a JS function that operates Monaco editor's API. Let's suppose it looks likes this:
export function setTheme(themeName) {
    fetch(`./themes/${themeName}.json`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(themeData => {
            console.log(themeName)
            console.log(themeData)
            monaco.editor.defineTheme(themeName, themeData);
            monaco.editor.setTheme(themeName);
        })
}

It relies on APIs which are not available on Deno, so it's put as a static JS file. I tried to bundle it with an Island component here:
<Dropdown list={themeList} onChange={setTheme} />

This cannot pass the compile because the server always tries to render it server-side although it's actually inside an Island (As ChatGPT told me). My question is how to bundle the function with the component only during the client side. ChatGPT asked me to put related CSR-only codes with setState functions like that:
useEffect(() => setTheme(themeName), []);

So I used a function object to store it:
    const setThm = (themeName: string) => {
        useEffect(() => setTheme(themeName), [themeName]);
    }

But Deno still rejected to render the page as it tried to render the function server-side. Function also does not help:
function setThm(themeName: string){
    useEffect(() => setTheme(themeName), []);
}

The same error as above:
error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: document is not defined
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
^
    at file:///path/to/project/static/editor.js:2:1

    info: document global is not available in Deno.
    hint: Use a library like happy-dom, deno_dom, linkedom or JSDom
          and setup the document global according to the library documentation.
Watcher Process failed. Restarting on file change...

So I really have no idea about how to bundle the CSR-only function with a Fresh component now. What exactly should I do is correct?
Additional info 1
Here is some codes from static/editor.js, where the package of Monaco is imported. As Monaco always tried to use the window object which is not accepted by Deno, it's impossible to import it on SSR-related codes.
// The function to initialize the editor after the DOM has been loaded.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const require = globalThis.require || {};

    require.config({
        paths: {
            'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.33.0/min/vs'
        },
    });

    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function(monaco) {
        globalThis.monaco = monaco;

        monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor'), {
            value: '#include <iostream>\nusing namespace std;\n\nint main() {\n    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;\n    return 0;\n}',
            language: 'cpp'
        });

        setTheme("github-light")

        // Bundle CSR-only functions with components.
        const themeSetter = document.getElementById('theme-setter');
        if (themeSetter){
            themeSetter.onchange = onThemeSetterSelect
            console.log("Theme setter is set")
        }
    });
});

Now my soluction is to stop trying to bundle the client side functions with Fresh components, but to call the static JavaScript to bundle them mannually after the DOM objects are rendered.
Additional Info 2
This time I tried to write like this:
// Initialize the editor, run CSR-only after the DOM is loaded.

import { useEffect } from "https://esm.sh/v128/preact@10.22.0/hooks/src/index.js";
import { IS_BROWSER } from "$fresh/runtime.ts";
import { init } from "../static/editor.js"

export default function Init() {
    if (!IS_BROWSER) {return <></>}

    useEffect(() => {
        if (IS_BROWSER){
            init()
        }
    })

    return <></>
}

where init() includes CSR-only functions that operates the document object. I've taken multiple measures to avoid the CSR-only functions being executed server-side (like using useEffect and check IS_BROWSER twice), but this time Deno still rejects to run and claims that document is not available at all.
Task start deno run -A --watch=static/,routes/ dev.ts
Watcher Process started.
The manifest has been generated for 3 routes and 6 islands.
error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: document is not defined
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    ^
    at init (file:///path/to/project/static/editor.js:7:5)
    at file:///path/to/project/static/editor.js:38:1

    info: document global is not available in Deno.
    hint: Use a library like happy-dom, deno_dom, linkedom or JSDom
          and setup the document global according to the library documentation.
Watcher Process failed. Restarting on file change...


Can you show where monaco is defined? It's unlikely that setting the theme is the issue, likely, you cannot render the editor at all from the server.

It's... annoying, to say the least. Probably purposefully, to encourage server-rendering. Anyway, Fresh exports an IS_BROWSER constant from $fresh/runtime.ts. You can use a conditional on it to determine what to render:
if (!IS_BROWSER) return <></>

In your scenario, instead of
<Dropdown list={themeList} onChange={setTheme} />

You can use this:
{IS_BROWSER ? <Dropdown list={themeList} onChange={setTheme} /> : <></>}

For more information, read the docs on client-side components. Do note that it explains how to use context to make it more ergonomic, which seems reasonable for your use-case, so I'd recommend taking a peek.

thx for your inspiring idea. gonna have a try if it works in days

could u please have a look at Additional Info 2 above? thx a lot!

@Heavysnowjakarta import at the top of the page like that is synchronous and will be evaluated immediately, not just when you call init(). This can sometimes be fine, assuming they only try to access document within functions, but that's not the case here. Instead, use a dynamic import (import("../static/editor.js")) inside your useEffect(). This will ensure the module is not ran until you want it to be.

Additionally, useEffect is never ran on the server -- you can skip using IS_BROWSER inside of it.

Yeah, what @rschristian said. If you control "../static/editor.js" though, you could try moving the import side-effects into the init() function. You probably don't want to put the import in useEffect unless you have to, as that will both slow it down and add asynchrony to a sync callback.
